# shell script for startup/shutdown of jboss7 fails with "Unexpected end of file" Syntax error

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jboss

As per a website, I have created a simple shell script at--> /etc/init.d/jboss

This shell script is to startup/shutdown JBoss AS 7.1.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

But when I try and run the script I get an error "Syntax error: unexpected end of file"
and it mentions the last line number of the file.

I used vim to create the above file and the contents of the file are given below-- what have I done wrong here?

```
#Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
#Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
#Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
#Default-Stop:      0 1 6
#Short-Description: JBOSS 7.1.1 Startup/Shutdown Script
### END INIT INFORMATION

case "$1" in
    start)
           echo "Starting JBOSS AS 7.1.1"
           sudo -u root sh /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1/bin/standalone.sh
    ;;
    stop)
           echo "Stopping JBOSS AS 7.1.1"
           sudo -u root sh /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect     command=:shutdown
    ;;
    *)
           echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/jboss {start|stop}"
           exit 1
    ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `esac` to balance `case`.